# Spring - Choose repository implementation after bean creation

Tags: spring, configuration, conditional-statements, repository, javabeans

I'm developing Spring Boot application which persists data into MS SQL database. I'm tasked to add support for PostgreSQL, which uses same tables. So my goal is to add another repository layer implementation. But things gets little bit complicated.

It would be great if my repository layer could look like this:

```java
public interface RecordRepository {

    Record get(long id);
}
```

```java
@Repository
@Conditional(MsSqlCondition.class)
public interface MsSqlRecordRepository {

    public Record get(long id) {
        // MS SQL implementation...
    }
}
```

```java
@Repository
@Conditional(PostgreSqlCondition.class)
public interface PostgreSqlRecordRepository {

    public Record get(long id) {
        // PostgreSql implementation...
    }
}
```

However, it seems to not be possible in my case.

First of all, my application doesn't have database configuration in `application.yaml` file. It has to get these variables from remote HTTP server. My `@Configuration` file looks something like this:

```java
@Configuration
public class MyAppConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public DatabaseConfiguration databaseConfiguration() {
        // Make HTTP request to remote server
        if (something) {
            return new MsSqlServerConfiguration(...);
        } else {
            return new PostgreSqlServerConfiguration(...);
        }
    }
}
```

With this approach, I'm unable to use `@Conditional` annotation for my `DataSource` and repository beans, since `@Conditional` is evaluated while parsing `@Configuration` files. I need to choose right implementation AFTER `DatabaseConfiguration` bean is created.

I already considered this approach:

```java
@Configuration
public class RepositoryConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public RecordRepository(DatabaseConfiguration configuration, JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        if (configuration.getType() == MS_SQL) {
            return new MsSqlRecordRepository(jdbcTemplate);
        } else {
            return new PostgreSqlRecordRepository(jdbcTemplate);
        }
    }
}
```

But this seems that it is not working for me either, sice I'm using Spring AOP for my repository classes.

Does Spring Boot have some other mechanism, which allows me to choose right repository implementation after my `DatabaseConfiguration` bean is created?

Thanks

Comment: Make a interface with the common functions and implement it on both of the class where you have written functions for them (mysql and postgres). use qualifier to name the bean. Use application context to get the bean of required class depending upon the dataConfiguration object.

Comment: Create a wrapper for getting the properties, the wrapper should act like a `PropertySource` that way you can use whatever mechanism you want. Or you can detect based on the configured datasource (more or less in the same way the `DataSourceBuilder` detects it based on the URL).